# How to filter Core Data fetch request result

Tags: swift, core-data

how can I extract the last `apiCallsToday` value from Core Data fetch request output?

```
var result: [NSManagedObject]?

guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "ApiCalls")
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print(result!)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Console output:

[image]

Comment: you are not actually storing date object. You are storing date string, which should be easier. Format today's date in the same format as your dateString is and then set your fetch request to have predicate  NSPredicate(format:"dateString = %@", formattedTodaysDateString).

Comment: What happened with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your Core Data Object Model looks like, but as Sandeep points out, you're storing your date as a string. One possibility to correct this would be to update your model so that your `ApiCalls` is has a `date` attribute that stores a `Date`, not a `dateString` attribute that stores a `String`.

To extract a date from your date string, you would use `DateFormatter`:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Then, when you create your `ApiCalls` object, you'd store an actual `Date`  instead of a `String`.

If you want the most recent one, you probably don't want to filter it, but sort the results on the date key. You'd add a `NSSortDescriptor` to your `fetchRequest`.

```
guard let appDelegate =
  UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
    return
}

var results: [ApiCalls] = []

let managedContext =
  appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let fetchRequest =
  NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "ApiCalls")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(ApiCalls.date), ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

do {
  results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}

let mostRecentDate = results.first
```

Comment: To avoid fetching all the objects, when only the last is required, you could specify the reverse sort descriptor (ascending:false) and apply fetchLimit=1.

Comment: @pbasdf Great call! Updated